# Execute a personal trace32 function when line is reached during test

Tags: testing, real-time, trace32, lauterbach

I'm testing a real-time application on physical hardware via lauterbach-trace32 probe.

Trace32 documentation is too vast and very technical but I'm not able to find how to implement what I need. I would like to know if there is a method to execute a trace32 function every time a specific code line (under test) is reached in program execution.

What I need is something similar to trigger in database scenario, where an automatic event is raised every time a specific condition is satisfied.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always set a breakpoint, which executes a PRACTICE command every time the breakpoints gets hit. E.g.

```
Break.Set myFunc /CMD "PRINT ""Hello World""" /RESUME
```

So **this will stop your target CPU** when functions myFunc() is reached. Then the PRACTICE command `PRINT "Hello World"` gets executed and finally your target CPU continues execution (thanks to the option `/RESUME`). (Consider that double quotes escape double quotes in strings)

Instead of a single command you can also execute more commands (by using option `/CMD` several times) or execute a PRACTICE script.

If you want to trigger debugger actions on a specific code line **without stopping the CPU** on that code line, you would need a real-time-trace with external trace interface. So e.g. you would need an ARM CPU with Embedded Trace Macro-cell (ETM) or a PowerPC with Nexus interface. Furthermore you would need Lauterbach hardware for trace-recording e.g. a PowerTrace, CombiProbe or uTrace.

If you have a real-time-trace you can set a "trigger-point" on the specific code line and a execute a command when the "trigger-point" triggers. It looks almost the same way than with breakpoints:

```
Break.Set myFunc /TraceTrigger /CMD "PRINT ""Hello World""" /RESUME
```

So the only difference is the option "/TraceTrigger". Of course you should ensure that the real-time-trace is actually working with your setup.